# PHP echo in selection list with multiple selection options

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a bit of struggle putting together a selection list in HTML where the options or values are being retrieved from a table in the database. I get the following result:
[image: Select List]

As you can see this is not my intention, I rather have all options in 1 Selection List, with multiple options clickable.

This is my HTML Code (Bootstrap Framework):

```
<div class="container-fluid well well-lg">

     <?php while ($itemsrow = $query->fetch()) : ?>

<div class="form-group">

      <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>

<select class="form-control" id="sel1">

         <option><?php echo $itemsrow['Beschrijving']; ?></option>
```

The PHP Logic:

```
$conn = Db::getInstance();
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE user_id = $userID");
$query->execute();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you're creating new  elements inside the loop so yes, you will get a new select per iteration.

You should only keep the `<option>`-elements inside the loop:

```
<div class="container-fluid well well-lg">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>

            <select class="form-control" id="sel1">

            <?php while ($itemsrow = $query->fetch()) : ?>  

                <option><?php echo $itemsrow['Beschrijving']; ?></option>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: lol thanks, I feel a bit stupid but thanks for replying so quickly!

Comment: @Moya - No worries. Just remember to check one of the answers as correct so the question gets closed.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your loop into `<select>` tag

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1">
    <?php while ($itemsrow = $query->fetch()) : ?>
        <option><?php echo $itemsrow['Beschrijving']; ?></option>
```

Comment: lol thanks, I feel a bit stupid but thanks for replying so quickly!